# well pump kicking on and off every few minutes

Tags: plumbing

my well pump kicks on every 5-10 minutes even with no water usage. It runs for a half a minute then shuts off.

Comment: Is the water pressure staying constant, or fluctuating? How is the pump controlled?

Answer (score 1):

There's a leak, assuming the pressure is varying and the pressure switch is operating normally.

If you are not seeing a leak, the most likely one is in the check valve at the bottom of the well (though we don't have any information about the type of pump you have - on a submersible pump, that check valve is in the top of the pump itself.)

You might also have a leak in the pipe between the well and the house, or in the well itself.

Finally, you may be running water in the house without being aware that you are - water softeners with faulty valves have done this to me, and leaky toilets are another common cause. If you have a main shutoff valve after the pressure tank, you can shut that off for 10-30 minutes or so and see if the pump still runs every 5-10 minutes or not. If so, look to the well side - if not, look in/around the house.

Comment: And if you don't have a main shut-off between the pressure tank and house, consider adding one. It's a fairly essential troubleshooting tool for several problems, including this one.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me. I just changed out the water heater for a different reason and the cycling on pump stoped doing that. I was going crazy because that’s a lot of water to not be able to find. The water heater is propane. So it must have been leaking in such a way that the water evaporated when the fire came on to heat the tank.